# How to dynamically declare return type of function in PHP 7

Tags: php, return-type, type-hinting

I created method to dynamically go through object methods and create array with anonymous functions that will behave as factories.

I have a problem how to dynamically declare return type of anonymous function. I couldn't find the right syntax and I'm not sure if it's even possible in PHP.

I would like to create something like this in simplified version:

```php
$services = [];
$object_class = get_class($object);
$method_names = get_class_methods($object_class);

// go through all object methods
foreach ($method_names as $method_name) {
    // get return type of this method
    $method = new ReflectionMethod($object_class, $method_name);
    $type = $method->getReturnType();

    // use it as return type for this anonymous function (not working)
    $services[$method_name] = function() use ($object, $method_name): $type {
        return call_user_func([$object, $method_name]);
    };
}
```

But I'm getting syntax error here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible, even with all the string magic PHP can do. What you could do is something like:

```php
$result = call_user_func...;
return gettype($result) === $type ? $result : null;
```

or throw some exceptions if they do not match.

Comment: I'm passing that array of services to a library, that library knows type of returned class from return type declaration, that's why I'm trying to put it there, so the problem here is not unknown return value

Comment: Yes, the issue is enforcing that return type, which cannot be done in the function structure by using variables, which is why it needs to be solved in the function body itself. Though, you might be able to ```eval``` the return type into existence, but that seems like a nightmare.

Comment: so it's probably not possible by design? something like `function(): eval($type) {...` is returning syntax error too, not sure how to use it there

Comment: I'm no ```eval``` expert, but it would involve writing the whole function out as a string and interpolating the variables into that string. Don't do that though :P Just add some checks and assertions to the function body!

Comment: I see... but I'm forced to used return type declaration by external library, so either I'll try to write that eval() or I'll have huge switch to add typehint in standard non-dynamic way for each method, thanks anyway for eval idea!

Comment: I'd start reconsidering that external library, but it's your call of course. Just remember, with great power comes great responsibility! ```eval``` can really mess your day up if you're not careful.